# PowerShell Function syntax question

Tags: powershell, pnp-powershell

I'm trying to get up to speed on PowerShell and have some difficulty understanding how to specify that a function requires parameters.  The example that I'm looking at has to different functions, and the syntax for their parameters are specified differently.  Can a function declare parameters in two different ways?  And in this first function what is the Process command???  The syntax of the second function makes much more sense to me.

```
function Get-SPOnlineFileDetails()
{
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipeline, HelpMessage="SharePoint Online source site URL")]
        [String]
        $sourceUrl,
        [bool]
        $Recurse,
        [bool]
        $IncludeFileSize      
    )
    Process{
         Write-Host "###################### Pull Details From SharePoint Online ######################" -ForegroundColor Green
         Write-Host "Provided Source URL :"$sourceUrl -ForegroundColor Green
         try{
...
```

Second function......

```
function PopulateData($web, $incldeFileSize){
        Write-Host "Current Site " $web.url -ForegroundColor Cyan 
                  $libs = Get-PnPList -Web $web | Where{($_.BaseType -eq “DocumentLibrary”) -or ($_.Title -eq "Pages") }

                  foreach($lib in $libs){
...
```

Comment: Read the online help [about_functions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions?view=powershell-5.1) especially the section [piping objects to functions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions?view=powershell-5.1#piping-objects-to-functions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second example is for a "basic" function. It uses the same syntax that we have used in many other languages: the word "function", a name for the function, a left paren, a list of parameters, a right paren, and a code block enclosed in curly brackets. They are quick and easy to write.

Your first example is for an "advanced" function that uses a formal parameter declaration. (see LotPing's link). This example also includes code to support using the function directly in a pipeline: the "ValueFromPipeline" in the Param block and the "process" in the code block. (also see LotPing's link) The Param statement and the pipelining "begin{} process{} end{}" are not both required, just often used together.

> Can a function declare parameters in two different ways?

There's actually a third way to get parameters in a function by using the $args variable that returns an array of parameters. These are called Positional Parameters.

```
funtion AddTwoNums {
  return $args[0] + $args[1]
}
```

So, your examples are from two extreems of PowerShell functions, a simple traditional function (#2) and a PowerShell unique function that supports use as a pipeline "cmdlet".